# cannot get the attribute of html tag in angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want o get the value of and attribute in my angular controller but it is `undefined`. If it helps everything is inside an MVC.net application.

The simplified codes:

**TestCtrl.js:**

```
angular.module('CMM')
    .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, elem, $attrs) {
        $scope.name = "mohsen";
        $scope.api = $attrs.api;
        alert($attrs.api);
        alert(elem.data('api'));
        console.log('hi, I am here');
    }]);
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('CMM', ['ngRoute','slServices', 'slControllers', 'ngAnimate', 'smart-table', 'ui.bootstrap']);
.....
```

**usage:**

```
<div id="content" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <h3>
        <input type ="text" ng-model="name"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="api" api="/sl/asdf"/>
         ....
```

Comment: only way element would be exposed is if your controller was part of a *"component"* or ""directive"*. You should not be concerned what is in the dom at all in a normal controller. Read the ngModel docs

Comment: Could you explain a little about what you're trying to accomplish? A controller should not be used to interact with DOM; that is what you do with a directive. Directives can expose and/or consume controllers, so that may be what you need to do, but it will be easier to advise if you can give more detail.

Comment: @charlietfl I want to pass the api address from the directive template to the controller. So I'm testing it simply here.

Comment: @JackA. I want to ultimately create a directive which passes an api address to the controller which uses http.get to fetch the required data. Finally I can consume that data in ng-repeat inside the directive. Anyway, I have no success to make it work, and that's my main problem.

Comment: It sounds like you want a directive and a *service* that will fetch the data. I don't see a need for a controller in that use case.

Comment: @JackA. Exactly, and I know that a service is best, but unfortunately the code is implemented before I join the team and everything is like that! Anyway the problem is not which module I should use (I can refactor it later), my problem is why this code is not working.

Comment: Where's the directive code? Not enough pieces here to figure out what should or shouldn't work. Used as `ng-controller` this won't work

Comment: @charlietfl This code doesn't even have a directive. This is a very simple code: A controller which should read the api url from a tag.

Comment: But a controller has no element relationship and concept is all wrong unless you do this as directive. As already mentioned , normal controllers have nothing to do with the dom. How is `api` populated in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working as written because `$element` and `$attrs` are not injectable. As discussed in the comments, you can use a directive to get access to the attributes and reference the controller from the directive. This is not really the proper way to do this, but it can be made to work.

So your controller could expose a method that is used to provide it with the API value from the directive, like this:

```
.controller("TestCtrl", function ($scope) {
    this.SetApi = function (api) {
    $scope.api = api;
  };
})
```

And your directive can reference the controller and call the method to supply the value, like this:

```
.directive("getApi", function () {
    return {
    controller: "TestCtrl",
    link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
      controller.SetApi(attr.api);
    }
  };
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/n5t6pfcc/

Comment: Thanks, it's working and more important, now I know the mechanism better. By the way, it would be great if you provide a link or briefly explain that why those services are not injectable.